# Passing parameters to a constructor, which are properties of an object class

Tags: c#, oop, parameters, constructor

I'm very new to C#, and the realm of programming. I've been carrying out some exercises in books and YouTube videos to wrap my head around many of these concepts.

Currently, I'm stuck on this issue. I have a small application for a Consignment Shop, and I was working on removing the hard coded sample data, and having the program read data from text files.

Here is my Vendor class:

```
public class Vendor
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Vendor(string firstName, string lastName)
    {

        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

This essentially takes my .csv file of Vendors and pushes them into a string array, creates the object and fills it's properties with array values, then adds the item to a list of type Vendor. This method throws no errors.

```
private void ReadFromFile()
{
    string line = "";                
    while ((line = myReader1.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] data = line.Split(',');                    
        Vendor v = new Vendor(data[0], data[1]);
        store.Vendors.Add(v);
    }
}
```

When I try this same solution for adding Items to a list, I would like to pass in the "Owner" of the item, which is a property of type Vendor, located in my Items class. Since I couldn't get a working solution on passing an object as a parameter in constructor, I decided to stick with passing formal data types. I basically want to use the Vendor's properties of First Name & Last Name, and set those as the Item Owner's first and last name.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Title { get; set; }        

    public decimal Price { get; set; }             

    public Vendor Owner { get; set; }

    public Item(string title, decimal price, string fName, string lName)
    {
        Title = title;            
        Price = price;
        Item.Owner.FirstName = fName; // this is what I want to do
        Item.Owner.LastName = lName; // throws objref error
    } 
}

//Input file format: title,price,fname,lname
while ((line = myReader2.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] data2 = line.Split(',');
    decimal price = decimal.Parse(data2[1]);                              
    Item i = new Item(data2[0],price,data2[2],data2[3]);                
    store.Items.Add(i);
}
```

The strings make it into the array, but when I run the debugger and check my store.Items List, every property value is set except for Owner, which is null. 
I know one solution could be to somehow combine fName+lName into one string, but I'm having a hard time understanding how my Item constructor needs to be set up in terms of which parameters it will accept. No matter what I try, the Oner property is never received a value, which causes the rest of my application to crash.

I've been working at this for a few hours, but I can't seem to come up with a working solution, or even a workaround to this scenario.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code even compiles, but what you want is this:

```
 Owner = new Vendor(fName, lName);
```

This essentially creates a `Vendor` instance and assigns it to the `Owner` variable. `Owner` is otherwise uninitialized and null, that's why you get the exception.

instead of this:

```
 Item.Owner.FirstName = fName; // this is what I want to do
 Item.Owner.LastName = lName; // throws objref error
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you for the quick response! And yes, in the code I posted it did not compile, I just wanted to show the idea of what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have exception because `Item.Owner` is actually not created. 
Fix it:

```
public Item(string title, decimal price, string fName, string lName)
{
    Title = title;            
    Price = price; 
    Item.Owner = new Vendor(fName, lName);
}
```

Also: why do you write 'Item.Owner'? It isn't seemed to be `static`. Use just `Owner`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this worked! I was trying to use Item.Owner to access the First Name and Last Name properties. Once I realized that wasn't working as expected, I left it to provide a clue into what I was trying to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: I just used Owner instead of Item.Owner, sorry I didn't mention that in my post above. Everything compiles and functions as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, if a class is a member of another class, you initialise it with new.

So in your constructor, you'd do the following:

```
public Item(string title, decimal price, string fName, string lName)
    {
        Title = title;            
        Price = price;
        Owner = new Vendor(fName, lName);
```